# Implementing a database record hash for keeping track of whether a record has changed or not

Tags: database, hash

I have database schema for an integration project in which I need to be able to query for records that have *changed*, *but only based on a given set of fields* within that record.

So, for instance, here's an example table:

CUSTOMERS

- ID
- Name
- Phone
- Fax
- Balance

I need to be to query to fetch records whose Name, Phone, or Fax fields have changed. However, other fields should not be taken into account, i.e. if *just the Balance field changes*, my query *should not* pull that record in (thus, an timestamp field that updates automatically whenever the record is modified *does not work*).

Also, this has to run on a number of different databases and platforms, so TRIGGERS or something similar are not really an option unless they'll run on MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, and SQLLite.

The fields are modified by a third-party application that I can't modify, so I can't just add a flag and have the third-party application set the flag to TRUE whenever it modifies a relevant field.

My initial solution to this is to calculate a HASH of the relevant fields and store it in a new field 'LastHash' or something. Then, I can calculate the hash of the relevant fields for the data currently in the record, and if it doesn't match the stored LastHash, I know it's changed.

That seems pretty messy... but it seems like it will work. Is there a better way? If not, is there a good way to implement that hash so it's efficient and not too time-consuming to extract those changed records?

**EDIT**

Some clarifications: Both my application *and* the other application update and insert into these tables. I *can* make my application calculate the initial hash. I can't make the other application calculate it though.

Timestamp columns that automatically update whenever a record changes are do-able, those are easy enough to replicate in all database systems using different column types or very simple triggers.

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION**

If hashing is the way to go... is there any sort of efficient hash algorithm that won't take forever to calculate on all of these records? MD5 or SHA1 might work, but they seem like they'd be *sllloowwww*.

Comment: How would you insert/update that hash without the use of triggers or modifying the app that does the inserts?

Comment: EDIT: I can make my application calculate the initial hash. I can't make the other application calculate it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a tough one.  You're still going to have to table scan (or index scan), since YOU have to calculate the new hash and compare it to the old hash stored.

If triggers are not possible because of cross-platform concerns, you might be able to have the database engine calculate the current hash (i.e. persisted computed column - effectively like a trigger).  This is also cross-platform problem, though!  Then if you index the current hash and your hash, it's a relatively easier search.

Can you at least use the timestamp field to reduce the number of hashes you need to check?

Another thing to remember is that there's no such thing as a perfect hash function, so you could potentially have false negatives (inadvertent hash collision leads to a change not being detected).  Is that (astronomically small) risk worth taking?

Comment: The idea of using the timestamps together with the hash is a good one, I like that. That should keep performance much better. 

I think the likelihood of finding a hash collision is pretty low. I could use SHA1 or something if I found MD5 wasn't enough.

Comment: Don't use a one-way cryptographic hash if you don't need too.  MD5 and SHA1 (though vulnerable) are designed as cryptographic hashes.  Using something like CRC32 or CRC64 will be MUCH more performant.

Comment: @scotru   -   CRC should not be used for change-tracking. I am basing this on this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7509974/1631910

Answer (score 0):

I would standardize how your application checks for a difference, not how the database implements it.  Try something like using a view with a particular column that signifies a change.  Then use the proper tricks implemented in each database to make that view a reality.  Code that depends on checking for this difference would then be the same, using the same view and column.

Comment: Splitting the columns into two tables *is not* an option. I can't change the other third-party application to accommodate that database change.