# Convert float to int bitwise without casting

Tags: java

I'm trying to checksum an array of floats. Therefore I want to convert them to integers bitwise. Is there any fast way to this not manipulating the bytes by myself?

Comment: Something like [`Float.floatToRawIntBits()`?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits-float-)

Comment: Yes, thanks! Actually, what is the difference between floatToIntBits() and floatToRawIntBits()? The handling of NaN?

Comment: Yes, if the actual number is representing a `NaN` value then the two methods return different values. `floatToIntBits()` returns the same canonical value for all possible `NaN` values while `floatToRawIntBits()` returns different values, depending on the actual `float` `NaN` value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the internal, bitwise representation of a `float` with [`Float.floatToRawIntBits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits-float-). You can then use the returned `int` to create a checksum:

```
int checksum = 0;
for (float value : floatArray) {
  checksum += Float.floatToRawIntBits(value);
}
```

Depending on your use case, you might also use [`Float.floatToIntBits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits-float-) which returns the canonical value `0x7fc00000` for all `NaN` values.

As for the checksum calculation itself, I took the simplest approach of just summing up the values. There are better checksum algorithms which are more robust against specific flipped bit patterns - once you have the `int` values, you can use them with any checksum algorithm you like (CRC, MD5, SHA2, or something else).

For more information, see for example

- [When is CRC more appropriate to use than MD5/SHA1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996843/when-is-crc-more-appropriate-to-use-than-md5-sha1)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum

Comment: I suggest using a multiplier to create a simple hash. But this does the job +1