# Time complexity of MD5

Tags: hash, cryptography, time-complexity, md5

What is the time complexity of the MD5 algorithm? I couldn't find a definitive answer online. I think the complexity is O(n) but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Time complexity of what? What is n? MD5 processes data in blocks of 512 bit, doing 4 rounds of [some internal operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Algorithm) (sometimes it may add one more block to the data - "the message is padded so that its length is divisible by 512"). So, if n is bytes, it does `roundup(8*n/512)` operations which is `O(n)` in Uniform Cost model (real memory hierarchy has nonuniform access cost for different layers/sizes).

Comment: Yes, for `n` byte or bits the complexity of MD5 is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 6):

`O(n)` as mentioned by DuBuisson and osgx in the comments.