# What is the time complexity of CRC and how does it compare to MD5?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, md5, crc

I wanted to compare the CRC algorithm to the MD5 algorithm for computational complexity. I found the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625569/time-complexity-of-md5) that states that MD5 is O(n).

**What is the time complexity of CRC? How does the time-complexity of CRC compare to MD5?**

My guess is O(n) as well, since it has to look at all the data to be computed. However, @defines states in his answer that ["CRC is computationally much less complex than MD5"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996843/when-is-crc-more-appropriate-to-use-than-md5-sha1/7509974#:%7E:text=CRC%20is%20computationally%20much%20less,hashing%20function%20such%20as%20MD5).

Comment: It seems that CRC must be O(n) also as its processing time increases or decreases in direct proportion to the input size.

Comment: They have the same complexity O(n). In the context of what you've read, "complex" means "complicated" and not "computational complexity".

Comment: You can compare the [wiki example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Pseudocode) to the crc64c() function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60270174/60271106#60271106). The CRC can be sped up to be 20 to 30 times faster than crc64c() using XMM registers and carryless multiply (PCLMULQDQ) in assembly. MD5 can only be sped up somewhat by using XMM registers.

Comment: (The cost increases in proportion with problem size for both: upper bound in O(n), lower bound in Ω(n): cost in Θ(n). The constant factors *do* differ.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, CRC is O(*n*), where *n* is the length of the sequence. What matters is the constant factor in front of the *n*.

Comment: yes they both are `O(n)` ... however the CRC32 C++ implementation is 13 lines of code with single for loop using XOR the MD5 is  3 pages of code with sub functions. So the MD5 as much slower from the runtime perspective btw SHA1 is 5 pages long (also `O(n)`) with much more sub-functions so its a magnitude slower than MD5

Comment: Yes, MD5 and SHA1 and others are slower than a CRC. But it has little to do with the number of lines of code. Often you need more lines of code to make something much _faster_. For example, a bit-wise CRC is 14 lines of code. A byte-wise CRC that is more than ten times as fast is 54 lines of code. A word-wise CRC that's about twice as fast again is 376 lines of code.

Comment: Yep I know but those implementations are mine with the same coding style doing almost the same things so number of lines + density of sub function calls is sort of metric (as the stuff is pretty similar) however for generic code you're right. Btw the CRC32 implementation is using LUT so its the same speed as bit wise CRC ...

Comment: @Spektre I don't understand that last statement. A byte-wise lookup table CRC is about 20 times as fast as a bit-wise CRC.

Comment: @MarkAdler How do I best quantify the constant factor? By counting operations per byte of data? (I am assuming this to be run on a micro controller without multi-processing capabilities)

Comment: @avgJoe You can try to count operations, but it is far easier and much more accurate to simply implement them and measure the execution time on your target processor.

Comment: @avgJoe direct measurement of the runtime on targeted system is the only way as the same code might behave very differently on different computing HW architectures in respect to runtime.

Comment: @MarkAdler I taught you got the fastest bitwise CRC so also LUT in mind....

Comment: @MarkAdler - I don' t understand your lines of code comment. A function to generate a table is about 16 lines, and a CRC function that uses the table is about 8 lines. Also why is using a byte wise look up table 20x faster than looping 8 times to cycle 8 bits for every byte processed by a CRC function?

Comment: @rcgldr Yes, you're right. In the olden days, and nowadays unoptimized (-O0), the byte-wise is 18 times as fast as the bit-wise. But with modern optimizers (-O3) it's only four times as fast.

Comment: @rcgldr I was counting pre-generated tables in the lines of code.

Comment: @MarkAdler - even with optimization for byte wise table lookup, assembly based "folding" code for CRC using XMM registers and carryless multiply is about 30 times as fast on my system. MD5 could also be sped up somewhat with XMM registers (parallel operations), but no where close to the 30x speed up for CRC.

Comment: @rcgldr Do you have a reference for calculating big O that I could use?

Comment: @Arash - you can find table based implementations for CRC doing a search here at Stack Overflow. For the assembly based "folding" code, you can find examples for Windows | Visual Studio at this [github repository](https://github.com/jeffareid/crc). The assembly code is over 550 lines.

Comment: @MarkAdler what is O(64 bit CRC)? by the length of the sequence you mean length of data or CRC bits?

Comment: How we can relate the complexity to data length?

Comment: n is the length of the data.